# https everywhere

Tags: ssl, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the pros and cons of a 100% HTTPS site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055131/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-100-https-site)

Is there any reason not to use https on every page of a site?

Comment: When the content doesn't require any sort of encryption or security.

Comment: This seems similar to the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055131/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-100-https-site

Hope this helps.

Comment: When the site is under so much load that it can not handle the extra ssl overhead (but in that case you will be looking for an ssl off-load solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SSL costs more bandwidth.
- SSL costs processor cycles, both on the server and the client.
- Both things cost loading/processing time.

Comment: SSL doesn't cost always more bandwidth, because the encryption begins always with a compression (intending to make the compressed data more random, but making it shorter as well). Although it has some overhead, too - it depends on the case, which will be bigger. If you download a big, compressable file over https, you will experience big bandwidth shrinking.